# Amazon CloudDistribution slow update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Having Amazon S3 and CloudFront enabled for the S3 content (actually serve static website). Any updates to the bucket takes randomly from 15 minutes to 1 day. What can I do with settings to make this faster?

Comment: What kind of updates are you talking about?

Comment: If I replace static file (e.g. html file within bucket) and this file represents one of my static site page..

Comment: How are you applying this update from AWS console or CLI?

Comment: I just do changes in S3 bucket directly (basically it is over script, but it is similar to manual file changes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you update the object in S3 you have to remove the object from the CloudFront cache so that CloudFront will go back to S3 to get the new version. This is called "cache invalidation". Since you aren't doing this, CloudFront isn't going back to check for a new version until the cache expires, which is why it is taking so long for the new version to show up.

You can read about invalidating CloudFront cache [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html).

Comment: Now it is clear. Is this TTL (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)?

Comment: @Evgeny yes, the TTL specifies how long CloudFront waits before automatically checking for a new version. A long TTL is good if your files don't change very often. For S3 objects I would suggest using a large TTL and performing manual cache invalidation when you update the objects.

Comment: We keep S3 static website for KB management (Knowledge Base) of our software. From time to time we have things changed so this actually happen few times. Thanks for your help Mark!